# Robotium Assertion Failing

Tags: java, android, testing, junit, robotium

When I run a test with Robotium, I use an assertion to verify that there is specific text on the page, but it fails. However, when I run the test without the assertion, the test passes. Why would this be?

Here is my code:

```
import com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.Smoke;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class ODPRobotiumTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 {

    private static final String TARGET_PACKAGE_ID = "com.gravitymobile.app.hornbill";
    private static final String LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME = "com.vzw.odp.LaunchActivity";

    private static Class<?>launcherActivityClass;

    static{
        try{
            launcherActivityClass = Class.forName(LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "deprecation" })
    public ODPRobotiumTest() throws ClassNotFoundException{
        super(TARGET_PACKAGE_ID, launcherActivityClass);
    }

    private Solo solo;

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception{
        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    }

    @Smoke
    public void testLine1(){

        try {
            assertTrue(solo.searchText("Easy to Find")) ;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
    @Smoke
    public void testLine2(){


            try{
        solo.searchText("Hassle-Free");
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
    @Smoke
    public void testLine3(){




        solo.searchText("Trust");


    }
    public void testLine4(){

        solo.searchText("Verizon Curated Wallpaper");


    }
    public void testLine5(){

        solo.searchText("Taco's");

    }
    @Override
    public void tearDown() throws Exception{
        try{
            solo.finalize();
        }catch(Throwable e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        getActivity().finish();
        super.tearDown();
    }
}
```

The test in testLine1 is the test that fails. But like I said before, when I don't use the assertTrue, and just solo.searchTest("Easy to find"), the test will pass. I don't understand.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out the content that I am trying to verify is HTML. So since Robotium doesn't work with HTML, or any other web component, it won't verify the text I'm looking for.

Thank you to all who offered help!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't assert anything then your test will pass cause nothing can fail.

Obviously the text you are searching is either missing from the screen, your configuration of the test runner is wrong or you are not even using the correct mechanisms for searching.

Comment: Obviously this is a horrible answer. If I could, I'd vote it down. Hopefully someone does it for me.

Comment: Why is that a horrible answer? You are asking why a test succeeds with no assertions. That is why it succeeds. No assertions in a test = test passes. Your assertion fails cause it fails. That's why it's there.

Comment: Stating the obvious doesn't make it a good answer and I wasn't asking why a test with no assertions doesn't fail. I want to know why the test is failing when it should be passing. The text is there.

Comment: Your question had two scales: a) why does the test pass without the assert, b) why does it fail with it

Comment: a) a test with no assertions will ALWAYS pass, b) if you assertion fails, that means that either you set it up wrong, or it actually fails correctly cause what you are searching for is not there.

Comment: put your stack trace on here which will help illuminate the situation.