# Handling fail cases in Robotium

Tags: robotium

I like to execute my robotium next test case if one test case fails. i have tried using try-catch, if-else etc but nothing works as i expected. When ever if it cannot able to handle any thing it gets fail.
 so i like to know
    1) Is it possible with robotium to handle exception?
    2) if is it possible how to do it?
    3) If not possible with robotium, whether is it possible to use robotium+java or robotium+junit, like this to handle this case?

Please help me on this. i have done many search regarding this then only though to post this que. so please provide some suggestion or solution

Lots of thanks in advance.

Comment: Post ya' code, bud. If you want debugging help, we need something to debug.

Comment: And yes you can handle exceptions -- check out this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092407/robotium-assertion-failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Robotium can handle exceptions with try-catch blocks:

```
    try{
        // The attempted code.
    } catch (SomeExceptionClass e){
        // Do something on an exception or just percolate:
        throw e;
    }
```

There's also an [example SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153668/how-to-expect-an-exception-in-robotium) that shows how to throw a new `Exception` as well without needing a try-catch. The gist:

```
        if (bundle != null) {
            // The attempted code...
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Here's my error message!");
        }
```

In fact there is an entire Google Group discussion about exception-handling in Robotium [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robotium-developers/IDRQ68oQstU) if you want more.